# Terminate nodejs aws lambda function in a .then or .catch function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Consider the following AWS lambda function written in nodejs.

```
export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  var file;

  await getFile()
    .then((filedata): void => {
      file = filedata;
    }).catch((e): void => {
      < Return error response and stop execution >
    });

  await saveFile(file)
    .then((result): void => {

    }).catch((e): void => {
      < Return error response and stop execution >
    });
  return {statusCode: 200};
};
```

If getFile fails I want the lambda function to just return an error and stop executing.

I can't return a response from the .catch statement because it's in the wrong scope.

I can surround the whole handler with try/catch and throw an error from the .catch statement like this:

```
try {
  await getFile()
    .then((filedata): void => {
      file = filedata;
    }).catch((e): void => {
      throw new Error("Error getFile");
    });

  await saveFile(file)
    .catch((e): void => {
      throw new Error("Error saveFile");
    });
  return {statusCode: 200, body: "success"};
} catch (error) {
  return {statusCode: 500, body: error.message};
}
```

...but I assume that there is a better way?

How would you do it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `await`, you have the option to not use `then()`, so you could  rewrite the getFile part to something along the lines of this:

```
try {
  file = await getFile():
} catch(e) {
  < Return error response and stop execution >
};
```

Comment: I updated my question with my try/catch-version. I'm just looking for a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `await`ing for the promise to resolve and then returning the value, you could encode the entire flow into the promise chain, and return the entire chain. The fulfilled value of the promise—either resolution or rejection—is returned to the user.

So your code would look like:

```
export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    return getFile()
        .then((filedata) : void => {
            return saveFile(filedata);
        })
        .then((result) : void => {
            return {statusCode: 200};
        })
        .catch((e) : void => {
            return {statusCode: 500, message: e}; // or whatever error
        })
}
```